# Sort Table using Jquery with Sub-Sort for Matching Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I am sorting an HTML table using the functions below which work perfectly for sorting the table based on the `<td>` values in whichever column `<th>` the user clicks on. By clicking on the column again the sort will reverse.

```
$('th').click(function(){
   var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0);
   var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()));
   this.asc = !this.asc;
   if (!this.asc){ rows = rows.reverse(); }
   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){ 
     table.append(rows[i]); }
})

function comparer(index) {
   return function(a, b) {
       var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index);
       return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB);
   }
}

function getCellValue(row, index){
  return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html(); }
```

I am now trying to do a "sub-sort" using another columns `<td>` values in the table to sort the table even further for the matching `<td>` values found in the initial column the table was sorted by.

So for example if 3 of the rows in the table all have matching values in the column that was selected to sort the table with. I would like to use a secondary column to further sort those rows based on the secondary columns `<td>` values. I plan to pre-define the column to use as the secondary sort when the column has matching values.

I know there are a ton of plugins available to perform this task but I am really trying to avoid using anything like that to accomplish something as simple as sorting a table. Originally I solved the problem fairly quickly using the functions I provided above but now with the issue of adding in another column to sort by, I am at a complete loss as how to approach this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.